# Get the zoomed coordinates of an image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview

I have an image in UIImageView. Have one point in Image on which I show pop over. Now when I zoom image the coordinates on which I show popover do not change according to the point, i.e. point is somewhere else and pop over else. How to get the coordinates of the point on zooming the image.When I do not zoom the image I get the right coordinates, but when I zoom the image, I do not get the exact coordinates of the point. Please help.

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: give me your popover code wer u show ?

Comment: simply multiply your x and y coordinate of popover with zoomScale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it using scrollview.contentOffset property of scrollview.

Example:

CGPoint p = CGPointMake(x-scroller.contentOffset.x, y-scroller.contentOffset.y);

Hope it works.. !!

Comment: Should x-scroller and y-scroller be the same scroller?